# sum of elements from different tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I need to create a function that can takes a list of tuples and a number. Example:
if the list of tuples is `[(2,5),(8,9),(11,19),(22,43),(47,50)]`, and the number is 14, the it should return 18.
The reason for this is at number 13 in the list `2,3,4,5,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19...` is 18 if all numbers are included:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18.
```

I now have:

```
def converting(tuples,index):
    values = [] #I will get [(2,3,4,5,6),(8,9),(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),(22,..,43),(47,48,49,50)]
    for tuple in tuples: 
        tupleValues = range(tuple[0], tuple[1]+1)
        values.extend(tupleValues)  #ex(2,3,4,5,6)
    if index <= len(values): #If 14 in the example is lower than len of the list, eg 42
        return values[index-1] #return value of 14-1, which is 16?
print converting(14,[(2,5),(8,9),(11,19),(22,43),(47,50)])
```

When I print this I get the message:
for tuple in tuples:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: i cannot understand your question..

Comment: Can you please explain your question/problem more clearly? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: can you explain how you got the list `2,3,4,5,8,9...`? Did you construct it somehow using the tuple list?

Comment: Why did you put 10 in the list?

Comment: Sounds like homework. Did SO become a homework help site? show some code and what you've tried so far and why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have a sequence of intervals and you need to extract the n-th number from those intervals. Here is a different solution regarding the algorithm used. Just count all the missing numbers from your interval sequence and add it to your value:

```
tuples = [(2,5),(8,9),(11,19),(22,43),(47,50)]
#tuples = [(2,7),(9,14),(17,20)]

def result(tuple, value):
    start = tuples[0][0] - 1
    for idx in range(len(tuples) - 1):
        if tuples[idx][1] >= value + start:
            break
        start = start + (tuples[idx+1][0] - tuples[idx][1] - 1)  
    return value + start  

for i in range(1, 16):
    print str(i) + ' ' + str(result(tuples, i))
```

Comment: This is working, but when I use another example, it doesn't.
Eg. result(13, [(2,7),(9,14),(17,20)]), should return 17, but it returns 15!

Comment: Sorry my mistake at stopping condition. Edited with new solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something to get you started. It can be made more concise, but I have tried to make it as clear as possible. You should also consider what you want to happen if the given tuples are  out-of-order, or if the index is not available in the list of values.

```
def valueAtIndex(tuples, index):
  values = []
  for tuple in tuples:
     #range(start, finish) returns a list of integers starting at 'start' and ending at 'finish-1' e.g. range(0, 2) is [0, 1]
     tupleValues = range(tuple[0], tuple[1]+1)
     #Extend adds all of the elements from one list to the end of the other e.g. [0, 1, 2].extend(['a', 'b']) is [0, 1, 2, 'a', 'b']
     values.extend(tupleValues) 
  if index <= len(values):
      return values[index-1]
```

Comment: Looks good.  Since the asker seems new to Python it might be worth explaining `range` and `extend` since they're the core of the solution.

Comment: I cannot get it to work. It says:TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, for the line: for tuple in tuples:

Comment: Thats prbably because your not giving [(2,5),(8,9),(11,19),(22,43),(47,50)] as a parameter, but somethin weired. say what your doing. Be more explicit and verbose!

Comment: Actually sounds like you're calling it with parameters inversed. Make sure you're not defining it like above and calling it like 'valueAtIndex(1, [(1,2), (4,6)])'

Answer (score 2):

This one-line works:

```
>>> sorted(reduce(lambda x,y:x.union(set(y)), map(lambda r:range(r[0], r[1]+1), [(2,5),(8,9),(11,19),(22,43),(47,50)]), set()))[13]
18
```

Tuple order in `[(47,50),(22,43),(8,9),(2,5),(11,19)]` does not matter any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one-liner:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([range(start,end+1) for start, end in t]))[13]
```

where `t` is the list of tuples in your question.

The solution is basically:

- Generate for every tuple a list of the elements they include with `range`
- Flatten the result (list of lists) to a list
- Get the elemnet you're looking for

For more fun, a lazier solution would be:

```
next(itertools.islice(itertools.chain.from_iterable(xrange(start,end+1) for start, end in t), 13, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `converting`, you pass the parameters in reverse order.
You should call `converting([(2,5),(8,9),(11,19),(22,43),(47,50)], 14)`